# Color shift after exporting!

Tags: color-correction, premiere, h.264

I've a bunch of videos from different sources that i need to export, i'm mainly using Sorenson Squeeze 9 for videos that i just want to transcode to another format or change bitrates, and Premiere Pro for editing and exporting videos, the problem is that both programs change the color of video, in other words, the exported file has a different color if compared to the original file. But i actually don't had touched any color parameters on both softwares. I  tried to compensate that difference with color effects but since i don't know nothing about color i reached no results.
Anyone have a clue why this is just happening?

Original File:
https://images.creativecow.net/287027/originalfile.png

Exported File:
http://images.creativecow.net/287027/exportedfile.png

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be to do with "color space". I've had similar issues with exporting videos from After Effects. Exporting using "REC 709" Color space usually gives me the colours I expect. You can read more about how Adobe handle different Color spaces here:

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/aftereffects/articles/color_management_workflow/ae_color_mgmt_wkflow.pdf

(PDF is offline, archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170830000622/http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/aftereffects/articles/color_management_workflow/ae_color_mgmt_wkflow.pdf )

Comment: Did you have any idea how can i change to Rec. 709 on Sorenson Squeeze?

Comment: hi tomh, which Rec 709 do you mean? in ae cc 2019 there are a lot of Rec 709. HDTV (Rec.709) ? or Rec.709 Gamma 2.4 or Rec.709 PQ ?